# Basic Program for encrypt/Decrypt : javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have written a very basic program for Encrypt/Decrypt and trying to encrypt just single string right now.
Encryption is working fine but in Decryption it is throwing an error

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error.

It is throwing an error on below line

```
byte[] decodedData = (rsa.doFinal(decodedValue));
```

I tried multiple ways and went through lots of threads but not able to find the solution. Can any one please help me with this issue?

The class is simple with 4 methods only, first is test method, next is keystore load method, and rest of two methods are encrypt and decrypt.

```
package XXXX;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;


public class EncryptDecryptUtil {
    private String publicKeyStoreFileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_51\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts";
    private String pubKeyStorePwd = "XXX";
    private String pubKeyAlias="XXXX";
    private static final String JKS = "JKS";
    private static final int CONST_16 = 16;    

    public String TestMethod(final String clearText) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, KeyStoreException,
            CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {    
        byte[] ecryptedAESKey = generateEncryptedData("TEST");
        System.out.println("Encrypted Key = " + ecryptedAESKey);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Key = " + generateDecryptedData(ecryptedAESKey));
        return generateDecryptedData(ecryptedAESKey);
    }

    private KeyStore loadKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
            IOException {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(JKS);
        FileInputStream tmp = new FileInputStream(publicKeyStoreFileName);
        keystore.load(tmp, pubKeyStorePwd.toCharArray());
        tmp.close();
        return keystore;
    } 

    private byte[] generateEncryptedData(final String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
            KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            Base64 base64 = new Base64();
            X509Certificate cert;
            KeyStore keystore = loadKeyStore();
            cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(pubKeyAlias);
            Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, cert);

            byte[] ecrypteddata = (base64.encode(rsa.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
            return ecrypteddata;
    }

    public String generateDecryptedData(final byte[] encryptedData) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
            KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            Base64 base64 = new Base64();
            X509Certificate cert;
            KeyStore keystore = loadKeyStore();
            cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(pubKeyAlias);
            Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, cert);
            byte[] decodedValue = base64.decode(encryptedData);
            byte[] decodedData = (rsa.doFinal(decodedValue));
            return new String(decodedData);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 as your system encoding? Maybe not... Just try running with
        byte[] ecryptedAESKey = generateEncryptedData(new String("TEST", "UTF-8"));

Comment: Thanks Jurgen for your response..!! I already tried without UTF-8 (just data.getBytes())  as well as with UTF-8. Also tried to pass the data from encrypter to decrypter as byte array, as string as hexdata but no success, same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java API makes a difference between certificates and (RSA) private keys. A private key, although associated with a certificate, is *not* part of a certificate. Java (fortunately) differs with Microsoft's .NET API in this respect, the .NET API is full of such bad design choices.

When you're trying:

```
rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, cert);
```

you should expect an error. The problem is however that this construct is sometimes used to raw "decrypt" RSA based signatures with a public key. So although you should always decrypt with a private key, decrypting with a public key is not explicitly disallowed (for the Sun providers).

So instead try and use `KeyStore#getKey` or (more modern but more convoluted) `KeyStore#getEntry` to retrieve the private key. That is: if you **do** indeed have a private key in the keystore and the password to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks Maarten for your response. I have already tried that as well.

~ rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keystore.getKey(pubKeyAlias, pubKeyStorePwd.toCharArray())); ~

Even above code is also giving the same error. Also tried without base64.decode and base64.encode, just passing the encrypted data directly and still it gives the same error :(

Comment: Do you get back a private key? Try casting the returned key to `PrivateKey` and see what happens... There are also methods for checking if an entry is (or more precisely, also contains) a private key.

Comment: Yes it does return me **sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@ffd74a7d**.

Unable to get the actual value though because there are no methods in lib to print it.

Comment: You should be able to cast the value to `RSAPrivateCrtKey`. Then you can compare the modulus of that key with the public key within the certificate, again after a cast (the cert should have a method to get it). Could you try that?

Comment: Hello? How are you faring?

Comment: Sorry for responding late, got caught up in few meetings. But trying to find a way to convert this into RSA private-Key as you said.

Comment: Finally Its working out now. I am encrypting with Public Key as per below
** Key key = cert.getPublicKey();
        rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);**

And decrypting with PrivateKey as per below and its working fine now.
** Key key = keystore.getKey(pubKeyAlias, pubKeyStorePwd.toCharArray());
        rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key); **

Sorry that I am not able to figure it out how to format the code in comment will find it later and will edit comments later.

Comment: One more question, This is Asymmetric way I guess, Is there a solution to do this with Symmetric Key? Can I use same RSA for solution with Symmetric or I should switch to AES?

Comment: RSA is only asymmetric, not symmetric. Note that the JKS key store format currently doesn't handle symmetric keys. Also note that RSA/PKCS#1 is vulnerable against padding oracle attacks. You may also want to look at `Cipher.WRAP_MODE` . Glad you've got it working, now get it *right* :)

Comment: Finally I have both the solutions working with Asymmetric and Symmetric Key. Thanks for the giving more info about Cipher.WRAP_MODE. It is interesting as well, but in my current case I am not worried much about security, because I need to store the data into local files only in case of getting error in transmitting the user data so it does not get lost.At later point same system is going to decrypt that data to retransmit.The best case here will be using Symmetric Key solution but it has a drawback that I have to maintain the same IV for descrption and for that might need to store IV locally.

Comment: You can prefix IVs in front of the ciphertext.

Comment: But thanks much for all your help, This was first time ever, I touched encryption and decryption stuff, but because of your guidance I have enough information now. Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help...!!!

Comment: I was reading about prefixing IV only and how this simple tricks increases the security as well :)
You seems very experienced person.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the final working code:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * Created by Suchit Pandya on 9/16/2016.
 */
public class EncryptLogic2 {

    private String publicKeyStoreFileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_51\\jre\\lib\\security\\cacerts";
    private String pubKeyStorePwd = "password";
    private String pubKeyAlias="certName";
    private static final String JKS = "JKS";
    private static final String SHA1PRNG = "SHA1PRNG";
    private static final String RSA = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
    private static final int CONST_16 = 16;
    private static byte[] asKey;


    public String TestMethod(final String clearText) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, KeyStoreException,
            CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

        String ecryptedData = generateEncryptedData(clearText);
        String decryptedData = generateDecryptedData(ecryptedData);
        System.out.println("*********** Decrypted Data = " + decryptedData);
        return decryptedData;
    }

    private KeyStore loadKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
            IOException {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(JKS);
        FileInputStream tmp = new FileInputStream(publicKeyStoreFileName);
        keystore.load(tmp, pubKeyStorePwd.toCharArray());
        tmp.close();
        return keystore;
    }

    private String generateEncryptedData(final String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
            KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        X509Certificate cert;
        KeyStore keystore = loadKeyStore();
        cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(pubKeyAlias);
        Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
        Key key = cert.getPublicKey();
        rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] ecrypteddata = rsa.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(ecrypteddata);
    }

    public String generateDecryptedData(final String encryptedData) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
            KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        X509Certificate cert;
        KeyStore keystore = loadKeyStore();
        Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
        Key key = keystore.getKey(pubKeyAlias, pubKeyStorePwd.toCharArray());
        rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decodedValue = base64.decode(encryptedData);
        byte[] decodedData = (rsa.doFinal(decodedValue));
        return new String(decodedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to give you a warning, using RSA encryption for anything other that carefully crafted data for session keys or fancy group arithmetics is highly risky. The math around it is hard to understand, the thing is slow, not to mention size limted. You better use hybrid mode like intially tried.

Comment: @eckes: I already have done research, and still RSA fits my requirement. I am using it for carefully crafted data only. My data is encrypted and decrypted by on same server only and getting stored on disc temporarily in case of error scenarios. Its never greater than 16 bytes.  I understand all the risk here. I just posted this solution so if any one else looking for working RSA code they can find it. Please do not mark the answer as negative.

Comment: @eckes: If you will follow the conversation, whole point of this post was to get working solution with RSA and this is a valid answer for RSA solution.